# C# - Cross Thread Error using Async and Await on TextBox

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to Async and Await and have created a simple project in order to understand how it works.
For this, I have a simple Windows Form application that has 2 elements:

- Get Completed Items button
- TextBox showing all Completed Items retrieved

When I click the button, it should display all completed Items in the TextBox.
This is the code I have written:

```
private async void btnGetCompletedItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QueueSystem queueSystem = QueueSystem.NewInstance(75);

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    watch.Start();
    await Task.Run(() => GetCompletedItems(queueSystem));
    watch.Stop();

    lblTime.Text = $"{watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()} ms";

}

private void GetCompletedItems(QueueSystem queueSystem)
{
    foreach (var item in queueSystem.GetCompletedItems())
    {
        txtItems.Text += $"{txtItems.Text}{item.ItemKey}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error in

> txtItems.Text +=
>   $"{txtItems.Text}{item.ItemKey}{Environment.NewLine}";

The error says

> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'txtItems' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on.

I checked in Debug and a new thread was created for GetCompletedItems(). When I read about Async and Await, I read that it doesn't necessarily create a new thread but it seems to have created a new one for some reason.

**Is my implementation and understanding of Async and Await wrong?
Is it possible to use Async and Await in a Windows Forms application?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: `Task.Run` involves other threads, without going into too much detail on which threads and why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot access UI thread on a different thread. This should help

```
private async void btnGetCompletedItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QueueSystem queueSystem = QueueSystem.NewInstance(75);

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    watch.Start();
    var results = await Task.Run(() => queueSystem.GetCompletedItems());
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        txtItems.Text += $"{txtItems.Text}{item.ItemKey}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
    watch.Stop();

    lblTime.Text = $"{watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()} ms";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the thread from another thread in a following way. It does helps to avoid the cross thread exception in your application.

```
private void Thread()
{
    this.Invoke((System.Action)(() => {
        //your thread call or definition
    });
}
```

Comment: missing a `)`, 5'th line should be `}));`

Answer (score 2):

> When I read about Async and Await, I read that it doesn't necessarily create a new
> thread

This is true for regular async methods. Consider this:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        await DoesNothing();
    }

    private async Task DoesNothing()
    {
        // outputs the same thread id as similar line as from above;
        // in particlar, for WinForms this means, that at this point
        // we are still at UI thread
        Trace.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
```

> but it seems to have created a new one for some reason

This is what [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) is intended for:

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool

In other words, it *pushes* anything you pass it as a delegate to a thread pool thread. Since we are in WinForms, this means, that anonymous method `() => GetCompletedItems(queueSystem)` will be executed at thread pool thread, not at UI one.

Here's code sample from above with little change:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        await Task.Run(DoesNothing);
    }

    private async Task DoesNothing()
    {
        // outputs DIFFERENT thread id;
        // in particlar, for WinForms this means, that at this point
        // we are not at UI thread, and we CANNOT access controls directly
        Trace.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
```